# selecting search option from dropdown

Tags: c#, selenium, authentication

I am having trouble selecting a drop-down from the list of 3 (active, inactive, hidden) my code only select  (Inactive ) option , cannot figure out how to make Active or Hidden option, used Xpath and cssSelester,  image and html code attached

Comment: You given HTML code not include the parts of those 3 options, please add them in your question, otherwise we can to write the xpath and css selector to find option.  And you code is wrong because it's not to find the option from the 3 ones.

Answer (score -1):

There appears to be an input field, can you not just set that?

```
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@data-role='dropdownlist']")).SendKeys("Active");
```

Comment: I don't have an option to use sendkeys  method, it only takes from dropdown list

Comment: Have you tried it though? Usually any input element will accept a send keys command